# Firebase still isn't saving user info to firestore after auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I found a tutorial on how to save the user's data under the uid in firestore. My function successfully retrieves the data and authenticates it, but it skips the firestore save function and jumps to the next window. I have two questions, why is it skipping the store in firebase function and why isn't reading the newly authenticated user as the current user when I set it and go to the next window? Sorry for all the similar questions, I'm trying different ways to do this and none have worked for me so far. I have provided my code below.

JS:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize variables
const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore().collection("/studiopick/studios/users");

const element = document.querySelector("form");
element.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  // renamed from newStudio
  // don't use alert - it blocks the thread
  console.log("debug: retrieving data... please wait");

  // Get data
  (studioName = document.getElementById("studioName").value),
    (email = document.getElementById("email").value),
    (password = document.getElementById("password").value),
    (firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value),
    (lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value),
    (phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value);

  console.log({ studioName, firstName, email }); // note added braces here

  // Validate input fields
  if (!validate_email(email) || !validate_password(password)) {
    // TODO: replace this alert with updating the form with an error message
    alert("Error with email or password");
    return false; // cancel submission
  }

  if (
    !validate_field(firstName) ||
    !validate_field(lastName) ||
    !validate_field(phoneNumber) ||
    !validate_field(studioName)
  ) {
    // TODO: replace this alert with updating the form with an error message
    alert("One or More Extra Fields is Outta Line!!");
    return false; // cancel submission
  }

  console.log("Info grab successful");

  // creates the user, and waits for it to finish being created
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function (userCredential) {
      usersRef.doc(`${userCredential.user.uid}`).set({
        studioName: studioName,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        email: email,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        uid: userCredential.user.uid,
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // [START_EXCLUDE]
      if (errorCode == "auth/weak-password") {
        alert("The password is too weak.");
      } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);
      // [END_EXCLUDE]
    });

  const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  // once the above tasks succeed, navigate to the dashboard.
  window.location.href = "studiodash.html?id=" + uid;

  return false;
});

// Validate Functions
function validate_email(email) {
  expression = /^[^@]+@\w+(\.\w+)+\w$/;
  if (expression.test(email) == true) {
    // Email is good
    return true;
  } else {
    // Email is not good
    return false;
  }
}

function validate_password(password) {
  // Firebase only accepts lengths greater than 6
  if (password < 6) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function validate_field(field) {
  if (field == null) {
    return false;
  }

  if (field.length <= 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out myself. Hope this helps someone:

```js
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log("firebase ===", firebase);

// Initialize variables
const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore().collection("/studiopick/studios/users");

const element = document.querySelector("form");
element.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  // renamed from newStudio
  // don't use alert - it blocks the thread
  console.log("debug: retrieving data... please wait");

  // Get data
  (studioName = document.getElementById("studioName").value),
    (email = document.getElementById("email").value),
    (password = document.getElementById("password").value),
    (firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value),
    (lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value),
    (phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value);

  console.log({ studioName, firstName, email }); // note added braces here

  // Validate input fields
  if (!validate_email(email) || !validate_password(password)) {
    // TODO: replace this alert with updating the form with an error message
    alert("Error with email or password");
    return false; // cancel submission
  }

  if (
    !validate_field(firstName) ||
    !validate_field(lastName) ||
    !validate_field(phoneNumber) ||
    !validate_field(studioName)
  ) {
    // TODO: replace this alert with updating the form with an error message
    alert("One or More Extra Fields is Outta Line!!");
    return false; // cancel submission
  }

  console.log("Info grab successful");

  // creates the user, and waits for it to finish being created
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(async (userCredential) => {
      console.log("userCredential ===", userCredential);
      var usersRef = db;
      await usersRef.doc(`${userCredential.user.uid}`).set({
        studioName: studioName,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        email: email,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        uid: userCredential.user.uid,
      });
      console.log("firebase.auth().currentUser ===", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
      const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

      // once the above tasks succeed, navigate to the dashboard.
      window.location.href = "studiodash.html?id=" + uid;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // [START_EXCLUDE]
      if (errorCode == "auth/weak-password") {
        alert("The password is too weak.");
      } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);
      // [END_EXCLUDE]
    });

  return false;
});

// Validate Functions
function validate_email(email) {
  expression = /^[^@]+@\w+(\.\w+)+\w$/;
  if (expression.test(email) == true) {
    // Email is good
    return true;
  } else {
    // Email is not good
    return false;
  }
}

function validate_password(password) {
  // Firebase only accepts lengths greater than 6
  if (password < 6) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function validate_field(field) {
  if (field == null) {
    return false;
  }

  if (field.length <= 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```